# Check if Telegram bot is already hosted

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a task to deploy a bot from a mobile application. The problem is that I need to make sure that the bot is not already hosted from some other source, in which case I do not need to do anything, but I did not find a way in the official documentation how to check if the bot instance is already running by token

Comment: Did you use webhook or polling?

Comment: @akop Not yet, I have not found how exactly to find out that the bot is running at all

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a precise way for it, but when i run my hosted bot with pytelegrambotapi in my pc it will shows the error:

telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

maybe there is a way to check it with POST
[https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates](https://api.telegram.org/bot%7Btoken%7D/getUpdates)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34024186)